# How do I uninstall a setuptools plugin?

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, setuptools

I have package which make use of some entrypoint `point` like this:

```
subscribers = {
    entry_point.name: entry_point.load()
    for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('point')
}
__all__.extend(list(subscribers.keys()))
```

I once had a module which defined a `DummySubscriber` with this code in it's 
`setup.py` file

```
 entry_points={
          'point': [
              'DummySubscriber = dummy.dummy:DummySubscriber',
…
```

or similar.
Now whenever I `iter_entry_points('point')` I also get this plugin (or the class), despite the fact that the package has been deleted (the source is gone and there's nothing in the Anaconda install directory. I'm at a loss as to how this plugin is still around.

I have grepped through the entire anaconda installation directory, but nothing was found.

How do I remove it?

Comment: Most probably the package wasn't uninstalled properly (or installed properly in the first place), with metadata still floating around. In the installation target dirs for python packages on your machine, search for `entry_points.txt` files that contain `DummySubscriber = dummy.dummy:DummySubscruber`. Before removal, check where it resides first - it may be wise to clean up the complete metadata dir/archive.

Comment: @hoefling Yes that is my hypothesis as well, but I searched in all files returned by `find . -name entry_points.txt` but there's nothing in there.

Comment: Do you get any output when running `python -c "import os, pkg_resources; print(os.linesep.join((ep.dist.egg_info for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('point') if ep.name == 'DummySubscriber')))"`?

Comment: Yes, actually, this returns a file `/home/share/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dummy_subscriber-0.0.2-py3.6.egg/EGG-INFO` which does not actually exist, which is why my `find` commands did not find it.

Comment: The egg file `/home/share/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dummy_subscriber-0.0.2-py3.6.egg/` did exist, however, so it's unclear to me how `find`ing `dummy` did not catch it. Deleting the egg solved the problem. If you want to make this an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, if the entry points are loaded, you can track them down by invoking the `pkg_resources` utilities:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: import pkg_resources

In [3]: print(os.linesep.join(('{}: {}'.format(ep.name, ep.dist.egg_info) for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('point'))))
DummySubscriber: /home/share/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dummy_subscriber-0.0.2-py3.6.egg/EGG-INFO
```

This will print the package origin of the entry point on the disk. Either it's a `*.dist-info` directory, or (as in your case) an archive (egg, wheel, zipfile etc.). Either way, you will get the name and version of the package (in this case, `dummy_subscriber==0.0.2`) which you can then try to uninstall using the package manager you're used for installation (`pip`, `easy_install`, system package manager).